# wordpress adding slash when trying to access form-action

Tags: php, wordpress

So i'm trying to make a PHP-uploading form. It works outside of any  wordpress-installation, but when trying to add it to a custom page i do this.

wordpressCMS->new page : `uploads`

then i name the file `page-uploads.php` and drag it into the right directory. I can now see the contents of the file.

However, in my form i've got

```
<form action="action.php" ....>
```

And when submitting the form, my url becomes `/uploads/action.php` and nothing happens in my db and wp is driving me mad, cant do anything custom in wordpress without fiddeling around with custom classes and using wordpresses own functions.

can i turn this functionality off, so that i can just ADD a random file with whatever code i want and it will show up as normal? Why cant i just CODE regular php-code without wordpress destroying everything for me?

Comment: Instead of a relative path of "action.php", try a root-relative path like "/action.php" or "/form/action.php" or whatever the public path of your `action.php` script is.

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos unfortunately it just brings me to /action.php/ and frontpage. (if file isnt found according to wp-bullshit)....

Comment: Hi please place your action.php file on wordpress root directory and use root-relative path like "/action.php", then please check

Comment: @Ashkar Hi, doesn't work... now since i'm trying to access a file outside of /wp-content/ it just gives me error 500, also it redirected me to domain/action.php/.

Comment: Then create another page with action in wordpress, and place action.php page's code in it, then in form action url give new pages url and check it..  You can use custom page for this if needed.

Comment: @Ashkar Already tried that. I renamed `action.php` to `page-action.php` and created a page called action in wordpress. then in the form action, i tried both action.php and page-action.php, neither yeilded me any result unfortunately.

Comment: One last idea, Please don't give anything there in action, 
    <form method="post" action=""> then in function.php file write action.php code with hook.

Comment: @Ashkar Thanks dude! The previous solution actually worked eventually, i revisited the previous comment-solution and i just had to give a relative path without extension to the action. So `action="/action"` did the trick. Now i'm just struggeling with write-permssions... oh god i hate wordpress xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143760/discussion-between-ashkar-and-joel).

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this, don't give anything on action,

```
<form method="post" action="">
            <!-- TODO -->
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email" />
            <input type="hidden" name="email-submission" value="1" />
        </form>
```

Then inside your funtion.php

```
 function my_theme_send_email() {

        if ( isset( $_POST['email-submission'] ) && '1' == $_POST['email-submission'] ) {

            // Send the email...

        } // end if

    } // end my_theme_send_email
    add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_send_email' )
```